# Set XTick of yyaxis to have integer ticks only

Tags: matlab

I have a plot with double y axes using `yyaxis`. I want to set `XTick` to have only integer values, e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, instead of 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6.

With normal `plot`, I can just use:

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = unique(round(ax.XTick));
```

to achieve this goal.

But this seems not the case for `yyaxis` plot.

Please help!

---

Update: here is a MWE to illustrate my problem:

```
figure('Position', get(0, 'Screensize'));

max_iter = 100;
A_history = nan(1,max_iter); B_history = nan(1,max_iter);
for iter = 1 : max_iter
    yyaxis left;
    A_history(iter) = randn(1);
    plot(A_history(1:iter), '-ob', 'LineWidth', 0.9, 'MarkerSize', 4.5, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b');
    ylabel('first yaxis');

    yyaxis right;
    B_history(iter) = randn(1);
    plot(B_history(1:iter), '-or', 'LineWidth', 0.6, 'MarkerSize', 3, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r');
    ylabel('second yaxis');
    
%     ax = gca;
%     ax.XTick = unique(round(ax.XTick));
    pause(1);
end
```

The above code will create `xticks` of 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, ..., 1 for the 1st iteration; xticks of 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, ..., 2 for the second iteration, for example.
**What I want is to get rid of all the non-integer values (e.g., 0.1, ... ,0.9, 1.1, ... ,1.9) in the `xticks`, just leave integer values (e.g., 0,1 for the 1st iteration; 1,2 for the second iteration).**

I have tried to add the commented 2 lines of code. But they don't give me the expected result, unfortunately. What's worse is that the `xticks` would become [0,1] all the time...

Hope this makes the problem description clearer.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example (full code with `yyaxis`)?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, I have added them to my post. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Probably one solution is by adding `xticks(1:iter)`, but this will cause overlapped `xticks` in the end when we have a large `max_iter`, say 1000. I am looking for a better solution that works without messy `xticks` when `max_iter` is very large. The `xticks` should be somehow self-adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually the `'XTickMode'` property which sets to `'manual'` when you do:

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = unique(round(ax.XTick));
```

You can change that back to `'auto'` to have the new xticks evaluated before you try to keep only unique rounded values. i.e.

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTickMode= 'auto';
ax.XTick = unique(round(ax.XTick));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! The `ax.XTickMode = 'auto'` is what I exactly need!!